# Fetch products in which Upc barcode starts with 890(INDIA) using php

Tags: php, api

I am new for UPC database. My requirement is **Fetch products in which Upc barcode starts with 890(INDIA) using php**

I registered in upc databse and i got a api key. But dono how to get products based on the barcode. Can any one help me how to code

Below is the sample code which i got after registration

```
// UPCDatabase.org cURL example. 

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array( 
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.upcdatabase.org/submit/curl.php', 
        CURLOPT_POST => true, 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array( 
        'upc' => '890', 
        'mrsp' => '280.00', 
        'apikey' => 'xxx', 
        'title' => 'BIOTIQUE MENS HAMPER', 
        'alias' => 'BIOTIQUE MENS HAMPER', 
        'description' => 'BIOTIQUE MENS HAMPER.', 
        'unit' => 'Per case' 
        )))); 
        $server_output = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch); 

        if( $server_output == 'OK' ) { 
        echo 'Everything went alright!'; 
        } else { 
        echo 'An error occured: ', $server_output; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand upcdatabase.com They do not supply complete subsets, only single requests. Therefore you would have to loop over all items starting with 890. For a 8 digit UPC that is just 100,000 items. But you will probably violate terms of use with upcdatabase, I didn't check.

In code:

```
<?php
$base = 890 * 100000;
for($i = 0; $i < 100,000; $i++) {
   $upc = $base + $i;
   //query the upc
}
```

### EDIT

I see now you are using .org not .com upcdatabase, cURL API is only for adding items not for looking up UPC numbers. Use JSON oder XML API instead.

Comment: See Terms of use, automated grapping through regular frontend is prohibited, you need to use the [XML-RPC API](http://www.upcdatabase.com/xmlrpc.asp)